# Angular - @angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am running and Angular app which has been compiled successfully using `npm install`.

Now, when I execute `npm start` I get the following response:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:57:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

57     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ChartComponent, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:58:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

58     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ChartComponent, "apx-chart", never, { "chart": "chart"; "annotations": "annotations"; "colors": "colors"; "dataLabels": "dataLabels"; "series": "series"; "stroke": "stroke"; "labels": "labels"; "legend": "legend"; "markers": "markers"; "noData": "noData"; "fill": "fill"; "tooltip": "tooltip"; "plotOptions": "plotOptions"; "responsive": "responsive"; "xaxis": "xaxis"; "yaxis": "yaxis"; "grid": "grid"; "states": "states"; "title": "title"; "subtitle": "subtitle"; "theme": "theme"; "autoUpdateSeries": "autoUpdateSeries"; }, {}, never, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/ng-apexcharts.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

9     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgApexchartsModule, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/ng-apexcharts.module.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

10     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<NgApexchartsModule, [typeof i1.ChartComponent], never, [typeof i1.ChartComponent]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/ng-apexcharts.module.d.ts:11:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

11     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<NgApexchartsModule>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/button/ng2-dropdown-button.d.ts:18:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

18     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Ng2DropdownButton, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/button/ng2-dropdown-button.d.ts:19:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

19     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<Ng2DropdownButton, "ng2-dropdown-button", never, { "showCaret": "showCaret"; }, { "onMenuToggled": "onMenuToggled"; }, never, ["*"]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/services/dropdown-state.service.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

9     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<DropdownStateService, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/services/dropdown-state.service.d.ts:10:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

10     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<DropdownStateService>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/menu-item/ng2-menu-item.d.ts:38:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

38     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Ng2MenuItem, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/menu-item/ng2-menu-item.d.ts:39:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

39     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<Ng2MenuItem, "ng2-menu-item", never, { "preventClose": "preventClose"; "value": "value"; }, {}, never, ["*"]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/menu/ng2-dropdown-menu.d.ts:74:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

74     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Ng2DropdownMenu, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/menu/ng2-dropdown-menu.d.ts:75:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

75     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<Ng2DropdownMenu, "ng2-dropdown-menu", never, { "width": "width"; "focusFirstElement": "focusFirstElement"; "offset": "offset"; "appendToBody": "appendToBody"; "zIndex": "zIndex"; }, {}, ["items"], ["*"]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/dropdown/ng2-dropdown.d.ts:38:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

38     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Ng2Dropdown, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/dropdown/ng2-dropdown.d.ts:39:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

39     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<Ng2Dropdown, "ng2-dropdown", never, { "dynamicUpdate": "dynamicUpdate"; }, { "onItemClicked": "onItemClicked"; "onItemSelected": "onItemSelected"; "onShow": "onShow"; "onHide": "onHide"; }, ["button", "menu"], ["ng2-dropdown-button", "ng2-dropdown-menu"]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/ng2-dropdown.module.d.ts:13:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

13     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Ng2DropdownModule, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/ng2-dropdown.module.d.ts:14:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

14     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<Ng2DropdownModule, [typeof i1.Ng2Dropdown, typeof i2.Ng2MenuItem, typeof i3.Ng2DropdownButton, typeof i4.Ng2DropdownMenu], [typeof i5.CommonModule], [typeof i2.Ng2MenuItem, typeof i3.Ng2DropdownButton, typeof i4.Ng2DropdownMenu, typeof i1.Ng2Dropdown]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/ng2-dropdown.module.d.ts:15:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Work Backup/DimensionsD/CodeRepository/UX/inwirement-ux/angular-web/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

15     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<Ng2DropdownModule>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Package.json**

```
{
    "name": "ng-flat-able",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --port 4300",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot",
        "build:prod1": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress ./dist"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
        "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "^1.1.0",
        "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
        "@angular/animations": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/core": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
        "@angular/forms": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/localize": "^10.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/router": "~10.0.2",
        "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.1.0",
        "@iplab/ngx-file-upload": "^2.0.6",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.0",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "^10.1.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "amazing-time-picker": "^1.8.0",
        "angular-archwizard": "^6.1.0",
        "angular-datatables": "^9.0.2",
        "angular-dual-listbox": "^6.0.0",
        "angular-highcharts-chart": "^1.0.2",
        "angular-pell": "^0.1.0",
        "angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
        "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
        "angular2-tinymce": "^3.3.0",
        "apexcharts": "^3.19.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.6.2",
        "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.6.2",
        "datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.5.2",
        "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.21",
        "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.5",
        "datatables.net-select": "^1.3.1",
        "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "firebase": "^8.9.1",
        "fullcalendar": "^5.1.0",
        "highcharts": "^8.2.2",
        "ic-datepicker": "^0.1.3",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
        "jszip": "^3.5.0",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "match-all": "^1.2.6",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "ng-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
        "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
        "ng-number-formatter": "^1.5.0",
        "ng-select": "^1.0.2",
        "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
        "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.2",
        "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
        "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
        "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
        "ngx-color-picker": "^9.1.0",
        "ngx-custom-validators": "^9.1.0",
        "ngx-lightbox": "^2.5.2",
        "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.0.1",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
        "ngx-powerbi": "^3.0.0",
        "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
        "ngx-tableau": "^1.1.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "~13.2.1",
        "ngx-treeview": "^10.0.2",
        "nouislider": "^14.6.0",
        "peity": "^3.3.0",
        "powerbi-client": "^2.18.6",
        "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
        "primeng": "^10.0.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.0",
        "screenfull": "^5.0.2",
        "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
        "stimulsoft-dashboards-js": "^2022.1.2",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.15.2",
        "tinymce": "^4.8.3",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.17.4",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
        "@angular/cli": "~10.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.2",
        "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.3",
        "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
        "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.3",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "agm-overlays": "^2.0.0",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
        "gzipper": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.5"
    }
}
```

**What I have tried?**

1. deleted **node_modules** and executed **npm install** again.
2. execute **npm ci**.

Still no luck.

I have NodeJS 14.18 and npm 6.14.15

Can someone help? as I am really stuck in it since long and surfed the internet for it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to come from an Angular version mismatch.
You have two version (or more) of @angular dependencies. That's due to the dependencies of your dependencies.
For example, ng-apexcharts@1.7.x needs a version of angular >= 13.0.0 where ng-apexcharts@1.6.0 has a [wider range of versions 9 to 12 included](https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts/commit/07e1a89ab4a356db7e649a1654a3c1718f5d321e) that meets your use (includes angular 10.x). So for that example change the version of ng-apexcharts from ^1.6.0 to ~1.6.0. [more info on semver](https://semver.npmjs.com/).
The way I check that in my projects is to look for angular different than 10 in your package-lock.json file to find what dependencies are using it and downgrade them.

Comment: I did it, but didn't work!

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you check which of your dependencies is using 'ng2-material-dropdown'?